# Is component.defaultProps necessary when prop is given initial value through defaultState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Within a redux application I have `defaultState` set within my reducers file.

```
/* reducers.js */
const defaultState = {
  items: [],
  loadingFlags: {
    items: false
  },
  userData: {
    name: '',
    id: null
  }
}

const rootReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM'
      return addItem(state, action)
    /* etc */
  }
}
```

And then using the value within a component once a value has been set:

```
/* UserDisplay.js */
const UserDisplay = props => <div>{props.username}</div>

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  username: state.userData.name
})
```

With an architecture like this, is `UserDisplay.defaultProps` unnecessary? I've seen it before where you'll have the `defaultState and also either

a)

```
UserDisplay.defaultProps = {username: ''}
```

or

b)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  username: state.userData.name || ''
})
```

Both of these seem redundant since reducers.js will always be setting the `userData.name` as ''. Are there situations (eg username is set async) where either approach A or B is necessary?

Comment: If `username` really belongs to the state of the app, I wouldn't have it as a default prop value since it really doesn't belong to the component but to the state passed to that component

Comment: A `defaultState` in your `rootReducer` is more than enough. You don't need a guard and you don't have to set `defaultProps`.

Comment: @MinusFour Ah, so defaultProps are only for props that are passed through as props from a parent component, not for `mapStateToProps` props?

Comment: @1252748 I'd only use them for the default value of a property that is related to the component and not to the state passed down from a state store of the app

Comment: @MinusFour How would a component have a prop if not from a parent component and not from `mapStateToProps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends, right? Will the component with the `defaultProps` be used by another container? Or with another reducer? in that case it's worth having default props.

If the component is never used by by other containers then default props are redundant.

As per [this tweet from Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/944931372820549632)

> If something is easy to do mechanically, makes you feel good, and doesn’t actually reduce bugs in your code, chances are you are wasting your time.

and

> Don’t separate “presentational components” until you actually use them twice. Etc.

If you need default props because you are running into bugs then yes. If a component is going to be reused by other containers, then yes having default props would be a safe idea.

I say judge this based on each context.

Comment: _Will the component with the defaultProps be used by another container? Or with another reducer? in that case it's worth having default props._ Why's this? If a component already has a default value coming from `defaultState` why does the frequency of its re-use change things?

Comment: If your application had multiple reducers and multiple containers then you could have a simple `userDisplay` component which could be implemented on a User Profile page and may also be implemented on another page such as an admin "Edit Users" page. This second Edit Users page may be using a different container and reducer but still implementing your simple `userDisplay` component so the `defaultState` of your first reducer will not apply to the second use case and therefore a `defaultProps` on this simple `userDisplay` component would make sense to safely render when used in multiple locations